# Major Y-axis skipping (Anycubic Kobra)

Tags: troubleshooting, layer-shifting

I have recently purchased an Anycubic Kobra, and the first two prints worked out fine. On the third print, the Y-axis belt snapped, so I contacted Anycubic support and they gave me a replacement one. I did a few test owl prints, but there was major Y-axis shifting on the prints.

[image: Images of two failed owl prints]

After I replaced the belt, I made sure that they were as tight as possible, but there was some slack, but I couldn't tighten them further. There is only shifting in the Y-axis, but it mostly only shifts in one direction (towards front).

What other reasons would cause a Y-axis shift like this? Is this due to incorrect belt replacement, as there was no shifting prior to the belt snap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this layer shifting. Even though the belt was too loose, I managed to use a rubber band to tighten the belt slightly. Now to prints go off without a hitch. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad you solved the problem! But, a rubber band sounds like a temporary fix, you might want to look into a [belt tensioner](https://a.aliexpress.com/_Ev0fQ57).

Comment: The printer came with a belt tensioner, however even with the knob at the tightest, there is still a lot of slack and the belt skips steps. When printing PLA, the bed (60) won't melt the rubber band, right? hanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Did you crimp on one of the brass end clamps yourself or was the belt completely assembled. I think the belt is just a tad too long. Rubber bands have a short (or at least a way shorter) life expectancy than the belt.

Comment: All the belt tensioners were already pre-assembled. Maybe Anycubic Support accidentally sent me a slightly longer belt, as if was fine before the belt snapped.

Comment: Okay, clear! If I were you I'd shorten the belt using a new brass clamp or repurpose the existing one. But, what works for you you should use! Happy printing!